# How to return ModelAndView Object from @ControllerAdvice class?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to handle exceptions from Spring MVC Controllers, but I have a problem.

My handle return ModelAndView object, but Spring doesn't use it.

While debugging, I saw that Spring opened the page in browser with standard spring error message and then, ran my method present in the GlobalControllerExceptionHandler. Why it is not calling that method first before going to the controller ?

I have this code :

```
@Slf4j
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = Controller.class)
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) {
        log.warn("Enter to handle method");
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("exception");
        mav.addObject("errorType", "errorType.toString()");
        mav.addObject("exception", "rootCause");
        mav.addObject("message", e.getMessage());
        return mav;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Today, suddenly it worked. I solved the problem with the following settings in application.properties:

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
server.error.include-exception=true
server.error.path=
```

I also created an error.html file that thymeleaf use if the error is not caught in my ExceptionHandler (I have no idea why ...)